# Android Get all nearest Tower CID for all providers?

Tags: android, network-programming

I used getNeighboringCellInfo() but it returns one entry only, seems to be the cell of my current provider.. how to get cell towers from all providers ?

Based on this question: How can I get cell tower data for all cell towers from all network providers in range?

Comment: What you have try?

Comment: @NiravRanpara ,i m try to making a list of all my nearby cell tower and also want to cid of all tower .